# Calculate height of div with dynamically populate ID value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div tag in in my JSP page. Its ID is autopopulated by other parameters that I don't have control over.

The div tag looks like this. I am skipping the contents in the div in this post.

```
<div class="parallax styleswitch" id="${nodeId}" style="${desktopstyle}" data-large="${desktopstyle}" data-medium="display:none;" data-small="display:none;" data-dtautoheight="true" data-tabautoheight="false" data-mobautoheight="false">
```

I want to calculate the height of this div. I was able make that work for div with static ID

```
$(".testt").height();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m7cyw70y/

How can I use the nodeId variable value in the JS to get the div's height? My JS code is in in the JSP page wrapped around script tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the JS code, use the auto-populated parameters to your benefit on server-side:

```
var nodeToGetHeight = "${nodeId}";
$("#" + nodeToGetHeight).height();
```

These auto-populated parameters could be used to populate an array that could then be looped through for multiple heights.

Answer (score 1):

You can use another attribute instead of the id. An example using the class attribute:

```
$('div.parallax').height();
```

You can also use a custom attribute:

```
<div custom-attr="myCustomAttr"></div>

$("div[custom-attr='myCustomAttr']").height();
```

There are even more approaches.

Comment: Yes, certainly. But I have a few more divs with same class but all of them have different IDs. So I want to use the ID to get the height.

Comment: You can use the `eq(index)` to filter which div you are getting: `$('div.parallax').eq(0).height();`. Also there are more ways to filter a colection of elements called by a generic selector.